# What's the french phrase meaning to be judged by the court of public opinion that is also used commonly in English?

Tags: expressions

What's the french phrase meaning to be judged by the court of public opinion that is also used commonly in English?

If I'm not wrong, it has the letter 'cas' in it...

Comment: What do you mean by "tried by the court of public opinion"? Trial by media? You really must be more explicit.

Comment: The question is too vague. Maybe it's "lynché par l'opinion publique" you're looking for.

Comment: @Dranna "lynché" est l'étape ultérieure: la sentence très négative !

Comment: As mentioned on ELU.se (in my opinion it's not good form to post on both!) the "cas" may correspond to *cour de cass'*, *Cour de Cassation*, but that corresponds neither to "public opinion" not to anything loaned out to English.

Comment: please be more specific, what do you mean by "court of public opinion"?

Comment: After "cas" (cour de cass') and several attempts at "public opinion", I'll provide *assizes* and *court martial* as French words that are used in English to describe courts. I doubt that we will find a phrase that fits more of the request...

Answer (score 1):

Jugement par une assemblée de citoyens (sélectionnés):

> Cour d'assises, *ou simplement* assises = Crown Court, court of assizes.

Jugement par le peuple:

> Vindicte populaire = public condemnation.

ou encore *jury populaire*.